# Encode existing blob instead of uploading from a local folder

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-media-services

I have a C# program that upload-encode-publish a video from my local folder.I want to change the "filepath" to a "URI of blob" in azure storage account. ie instead of uploading a video and encode-publish, process an uploaded video and encode-publish. Anyone kindly suggest a method to implement this.

```
namespace OnDemandEncodingWithMES
{
    class Program
    {
        // Read values from the App.config file.

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create and cache the Media Services credentials in a static class variable.
                _cachedCredentials = new MediaServicesCredentials(_mediaServicesAccountName,_mediaServicesAccountKey);

                Console.WriteLine("Upload a file.\n");
                IAsset inputAsset =
                    UploadFile(Path.(_mediaFiles, @"video.mp4"), AssetCreationOptions.None);

                Console.WriteLine("Generate thumbnails and get URLs.\n");
                IAsset thumbnailAsset = GenerateThumbnail(inputAsset, AssetCreationOptions.None);
                PublishAssetGetURLs(thumbnailAsset, false, ".bmp");

                Console.WriteLine("Encode to audio and get an on demand URL.\n");
                IAsset audioOnly = EncodeToAudioOnly(inputAsset, AssetCreationOptions.None);
                PublishAssetGetURLs(audioOnly);

                Console.WriteLine("Encode to adaptive bitraite MP4s and get on demand URLs.\n");
                IAsset encodedAsset =
                EncodeToAdaptiveBitrateMP4s(inputAsset, AssetCreationOptions.StorageEncrypted);

                PublishAssetGetURLs(encodedAsset);
            }
         }   
     } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-copying-existing-blob/. Example shows how to create azure media services asset from existing azure storage account

Comment: Thanks @George Trifonov. Finally found the solution.